# How do I write this in SQL view?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, view

create a view called StudentListByCourse. The view should contain these columns from the following ER model and the output should be sorted by the course name:

```
Course name
Student name
Student age
```

[image]

This is what I have but im not sure if this is correct

```
CREATE VIEW StudentListByCourse
SELECT *
FROM student AS s
WHERE courses AS c
SORT BY c.coursename, s.studentname, s.studentage
```

Comment: age is literally second column in your student table

Comment: _"This is what I have but im not sure if this is correct"_ - have you tried it? What problems did you encounter, if any?

Comment: No, I haven't ran the code.  I do not have my computer on hand at the moment

Comment: You have a mechanism for communicating with this forum. That same mechanism could presumably interact with an (sql) fiddle of some kind. So, the lack of a 'computer' should be no barrier to code development

Answer (score 0):

If the view is being made for MySQL, then the syntax will need to be corrected:

```
CREATE VIEW StudentListByCourse
SELECT c.coursename, s.name as studentname, s.age as studentage
  FROM student s INNER JOIN courses c ON s.Courses_idCourses = c.idCourses
 ORDER BY c.coursename, s.name, s.age
```

Joining is done with a `JOIN`, of which there are many depending on your needs. Sorting is performed with `ORDER BY`. The field names in your order statement do not exist, but you can alias them in the `SELECT`

Comment: For all practical purposes, there are 3 joins, (inner, left, and cross), so perhaps not 'many'